# Dialogue history encoding for multi-turn dialogues using Seq2seq

Tags: nlp, sequence-to-sequence, text-generation

In single-turn dialogue seq2seq models where the goal is to produce a good answer y to a query x, sentences are usually encoded such that x is fed to the encoder, while the decoder is only given a "START" token and the output from the encoder. Often, attention is incorporated into the decoding step by eg concatening the decoder output at time t with the encoder output and performing attention on the resulting vector: attention(y_t, encoder_{out}).

What are common ways to encode multi-turn dialogues? The idea here is that the model can be queried k times (where k is the number of turns in the dialogue) for one conversation and has to keep track of the dialogue context throughout to generate coherent responses.

A simplistic way to do it would be to simply concatenate the dialogue history over all turns and feed it to the encoder, but I am unsure whether different RNNs (eg LSTMs or GRUs) can handle longer sequences and still maintain a high feature quality.

Comment: Do you mean you want 5 different possible responses given a query and the  conversation history?

Comment: No, I mean I want a dialogue that lasts 5 turns. I will edit my post to reflect that, thank you for noticing the ambiguity.

Comment: Can you just give X as the entire dialog so far? Why wouldn't this not work well?

Comment: I am unsure whether different RNNs (eg LSTMs or GRUs) can handle longer sequences and still maintain a high feature quality. Is there some research on when LSTM/GRU performance starts to deteriorate?

I also don't know if you can just cram the dialogue history into a vector of fixed size, regardless of how many turns you take.

Comment: A couple options: Fuse the historical dialogue information and the current input statement information in the encoder[Modeling Multi-turn Conversation with Deep Utterance Aggregation][1]. Hierarchical Self-Attention (https://hrcak.srce.hr/file/379467)

Comment: Thanks so much for the resources, they are a huge help!